# Trying to write my output into an column getting: Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead error

Tags: pandas

here is my

example data,

```
Close

46.119999           
47.259998                
52.000000
```

and
this is how I create df;

```
data = pd.read_csv('logo_bist_merged.csv')

#this is justbecause last 413 rows are NA
data.drop(data.tail(413).index,inplace=True)

data.Date=pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data=data.set_index(data.Date)
data=data.sort_index()

#dataset contains 10 years of
df = data['2016-01-01':'2020-11-30']


df
```

my initial trial;

```
def Rm(prices):
    return (prices/prices.shift(1)-1)

Yield = Rm(df.Close)
df['Rm'] = Yield
```

My expected result from this is to see output of Rm in my dataframe as a new column.

as;

```
  Close       Rm

46.119999    NaN        
47.259998    0.024718            
52.000000    0.100296
```

Pandas returned an error as;

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:7: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  import sys
```

so I made this change;

```
df.loc[:, 'Rm'] = Yield
```

and I got this error;

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:376: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:494: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

I couldn't understand where my mistake is.. and I want to learn best way to do this operation.

my pandas version is: 0.25.3 and
my Python version is: 3.7.5

Comment: The problem probably comes from the way you get your `df` dataframe. Could edit your post to show how you get it ?

Comment: @jlesueur ok I just did and you just made me realize something, maybe indexing by date is causing all this. I'm also gonna try to reset it

Comment: @jlesueur fixed my issue thx a lot for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

It was due to indexing df by datetime column.

solved simply by resetting index as;

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```